# Why was my question closed?

Tags: support, close-reasons, closed-questions

Why was my question [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/105092/is-race-well-defined-for-hominids) closed? IT didn't even get a chance. It clearly asks a different question than the questions asked by the supposed duplicate. How do I appeal this, or am I just not going to get an answer? I'm concerned that this question will just be closed by the same moderator that closed my original question. Is it considered "off-topic" because it's about race? IF so, then why is the supposed duplicate allowed?

Comment: I think the linked duplicate explains well how the word "race" aligns with biological concepts with respect to humans (it really doesn't). If instead you want to talk about hominid species, well...they're species, so I don't see why it makes any sense to bring in the word "race".

Comment: https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/39664/27148 is another related question about the definition of species. I closed your question because I feel these things have been addressed sufficiently here, and there's no reason to generate another set of answers re-stating all the same things (that's why we close as duplicate). Open to other opinions, though.

Comment: I mentioned this on the answer, but the paper you linked  seems to answer the question.

Comment: @BryanKrause According to the wiki about "race" in biology, it is not as simple as you make it appear: "Sometimes it is used to denote a level below that of subspecies, while at other times it is used as a synonym for subspecies.... Races may be genetically distinct populations of individuals within the same species, or they may be defined in other ways, e.g. geographically, or physiologically." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_(biology)

Comment: @BryanKrause So, as my question on the Biology SE states very specifically, can there be a sense in which there is "The Human Race" among other types of hominids? I do not see still how the supposed duplicate answers this question. I'm not a biologist, and it's not obvious to me.

Comment: @DaddyKropotkin Did you also read the species one I linked in the comments here? ""Sometimes it is used to denote a level below that of subspecies, while at other times it is used as a synonym for subspecies...." is not how the word "race" is used with humans; if you use the biological meaning it doesn't apply to humans, yet clearly "race" is a thing that impacts how people treat each other in society.

Comment: I don't see the value in the hypothetical you're bringing up, and it hits on some very touchy topics that have very little to do about biology. Your question does not seem well-motivated: why does the answer matter? (beyond the misunderstandings about what race and species are which those existing Q&A already address)

Comment: I am not trying to refer to different races of humans, as I said in my question on Bio SE. I am asking about different races of hominids. Not sure why that difference is not clear...?

Comment: @DaddyKropotkin I've just read your question, and am afraid I'm confused by it as well. I think this may be because it centers on terminology (which is subject to debate) rather than some measurable aspect of biology. Maybe you could try again with specific examples included to illustrate the question? Like, do you mean were Denisovans visually distinct from Neanderthals, or do you mean were their genetics separable into clades, or do you mean did they stereotype and segregate from one another? I think you might mean the second, but it's not clear to me from what you wrote.